# How to build 2 solutions from a single TFS team build definition

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a pretty large complicated application that has a smart client front end in one solution and a web services layer in another solution.   We use 2 team build definitions in TFS 2010 to build the solutions.  We are still using MS Build scripts not the new workflow based templates.

How can we use a single build definition to build both solutions.  We are open to either tricks inside MS Build scripts or moving to the new workflow templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set two Solutions to build by creating them in an item group if I am understanding what you are trying to do

```
    <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../$(SuiteSourceBranchRoot)/MyCompany.Suite.sln">
      <Targets></Targets>
      <Properties></Properties>
    </SolutionToBuild>
    <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../$(SuiteSourceBranchRoot)/MyCompany.Another.sln">
      <Targets></Targets>
      <Properties></Properties>
    </SolutionToBuild>
  </ItemGroup>
```

You can also do it inside any build step with:

```
<!-- Build the deployment solution. -->
<MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionRoot)\$(SuiteSourceBranchRoot)/Company.Deployment.sln" Properties="Configuration=Release;" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build multiple solutions from a single team build project definition by definitng multiple `SolutionToBuild` items in your TFSBuild.proj MSBuild project file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SolutionToBuild Include="$(SolutionRoot)\A\A.sln" />
  <SolutionToBuild Include="$(SolutionRoot)\B\B.sln" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You may also have to modify the build definition's workspace mapping to include sources for both solutions.