# TFS Project with Multiple Visual Studio Solutions

Tags: tfs

Our team is looking at using Team Foundation Server v.11 (2012) to manage our projects. We currently do our project management in spread sheets. Our team develops software for internal clients only and there is a lot of dll sharing between projects. We are also using SVN for our source code version control.

We have Solutions for different parts of our applications: Common Library, Application Libraries (business rules, etc), Intranet Website, Internet Website, Windows Forms. Here is what our SVN structure looks like

```
SVN
    -CommonLibrary (VS Solution)
        -Source
            -CommonLibrary.Core (VS Project)
            -CommonLibrary.Security (VS Project)
            -CommonLibrary.Web (VS Project)
    -OurCompanyLibrary (VS Solution)
        -Libraries (Projects within this solution reference these)
            -CommonLibrary.Core.dll
            -CommonLibrary.Security.dll
        -Source
            -OurCompanyLibrary.Application1 (VS Project)
            -...
            -OurCompanyLibrary.ApplicationN (VS Project)
    -OurCompanyIntranet (VS Solution) (MVC framework)
        -Libraries (Projects within this solution reference these)
            -CommonLibrary.Core.dll
            -CommonLibrary.Security.dll
            -CommonLibrary.Web.dll
            -OurCompanyLibrary.Application1.dll
        -Source
            -OurCompanyIntranet.Application1 (VS Class Library Project)
            -...
            -OurCompanyIntranet.ApplicationN (VS Class Library Project)
            OurCompanyIntranet.UI (VS Web Project)
    -OurCompanyInternet (VS Solution) (MVC framework)
        -Libraries (Projects within this solution reference these)
            -CommonLibrary.Core.dll
            -CommonLibrary.Security.dll
            -CommonLibrary.Web.dll
            -OurCompanyLibrary.Application1.dll
        -Source
            -OurCompanyInternet.Application1 (VS Class Library Project)
            -...
            -OurCompanyInternet.ApplicationN (VS Class Library Project)
            -OurCompanyInternet.UI (VS Web Project)
```

The reason for splitting the code up into multiple solutions is because we can reuse the application libraries in different situations (Intranet apps, Internet apps, Winform apps). Also, the intranet and internet solutions contain multiple applications. This is our current structure. I'm not sure this is the best organizational structure, but it works for us.

The problem with switching to TFS is that one Team Project can't have parts in multiple VS solutions. For example, we would set up a TFS Team Project for Application1 so we could have a product backlog for that application. Application1 requires changes to OurCompanyLibrary, OurCompanyIntranet and OurCompanyInternet to complete the application but, using TFS, there would only be one VS Solution for Application1.

Here is an example of how we develop an application. All of the domain model and business rules our stored in the OurCompanyLibrary VS Solution. When we develop an application, call it Application1, we first start creating the domain model and business rules in the OurCompanyLibrary.Application1 VS project under OurCompanyLibrary VS Solution. Once the domain model is developed, we move over to program the UI side of things in the OurCompanyIntranet and OurCompanyInternet VS Solutions. These solutions are a MVC style website. OurCompanyIntranet contains a VS Web Project OurCompanyIntranet.UI that contains all of the views (.aspx files), css, javasciprt, etc. OurCompanyIntranet also contains all of the models and controllers separated by application (OurCompanyIntranet.Application1 in this case). Organizing this in TFS becomes a problem, because we want a Team Project for Application1, but that application can span multiple solutions and we don't want to have duplicate code everywhere by adding the same OurCompanyIntranet and OurCompanyInternet VS Solutions to source control.

How would you organize this in TFS? Is there another way we should organize our code structure that would make more sense? Any articles or websites out there that would lead us in the right direction would greatly help.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First, don't use multiple Team Project, this is a huge mistake that everybody make at the beginning. For the size of your team and what you develop: one Team Project is what you need.

You use two Team Projects when there are two teams of completely different people, working on a completely different project, with a completely different methodology/process.

With one Team Project you can still:

- Have many branches (related or not).
- Have the administration of Source Control at the tiniest level you need
- Split your project into sub categories (functional, technical, whatever you need) using the Area Path (which is a node tree) of Work Item. This way you can have one big product backlog or dedicated ones.
- Overall reports on your whole project or on specific area (still using Area Path, but in Reporting Services)
- Trust me on that, it's the best way to go and many many people (including me the first time) make the mistake to use multiple Team Project and have to paid the price thereafter. What you need is a good Source Control hierarchical structure and a good Area Path tree.

Concerning Solutions:

Having one solution per main component of your project is not a bad thing, developers can work on a dedicated subset of the project, to maximize the productivity and reduce the coupling between components.

But you still can have one global solution that reference all your projects and that will be use whenever you need to make changes that impact all your project. Having a global solution is also an easy way to build your whole project painlessly.

The issue here is **about cross component references**, if one component you develop (e.g. Application1) needs another component you develop (e.g. OurCompanyLibrary) then it creates a dependency between both and Application1 must reference "built assemblies" of OurCompanyLibrary.

Which implies either:

1. You must create a location somewhere in your source control to store the built assemblies of all the components that will be referenced by others. Maintain a Build Cycle to release everything respecting the right order.
2. Take advantage of the new standard which is [Nuget](http://nuget.org) and setup an in-house Nuget server (very easy to do) and build your own Nuget packages for the components that will be referenced by others.
3. The easiest way to go is including all your dependencies developed in-house in the solution to make sure they are built when needed. It's easy to do but your Application1 project will include most of your VS Projects. I don't say it a good or bad way to go, it's your call. Sometime the easy way is the best one.

Each way has its own pros/cons, and only you can decide which one is the best to go.

Comment: How would you handle assembly versions. Our strategy is having a shared assembly info file per solution, so OurCompanyLibrary would have a different version than CommonLibrary and so on. Would you now only have one assembly version for the whole team project? I realize you could have different version numbers, but is that the best way to do it or is the best way to have one version number for the entire team project?

Comment: If your final product is monolithic then all the assemblies can share the same version number and this number will be used to differentiate two different versions of your product. Now suppose you develop two products (for instance two unrelated web sites) based on the same component (company's core/business assemblies), assembly versionning takes a different meaning here, because the two web sites may use different version of the core/business assemblies and you may have different development cycle for the three of them (core/business, site 1, site2). If everything is monolithic, don't bother.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It's not monolithic. We have two different public facing websites that do not use the same business assemblies, but the intranet uses the same business assemblies as the public websites. I think I would have different versions for each of the web sites and libraries. How would you branch this sort of thing? Would I have a Main and Dev branch like normal and then a Release branch for each of the different websites?

Comment: Then each component (business, website, intranet) has its own branche tree (the branching model you use is up to you and it's a whole new story) and maybe its own development cycle. Consider using 1) or 2) to solve the dependencies, but if you have a lot of releases in a year I strongly encourage you to invest the time in setting up Nuget, it's an easy, clever and standard solution, you won't regret it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers They have helped tremendously. I would like to look at the Nuget thing a little more. Would you know of any articles on how to set up our common libraries as a Nuget package? If not, I can do some searching. It would be great to see the Nuget package and deployment integrated with the build process.

Comment: Scott Hanselman has great blog post and webcast, see this post in particular: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetForTheEnterpriseNuGetInAContinuousIntegrationAutomatedBuildSystem.aspx

Comment: Warning, Option #3 will cause branching headaches if your library projects aren't in the same folder as your main application & solution.  When you create a development branch, you'll lose the references to these library projects and have to manually edit each of their project file paths.

Comment: You want to create a team project in TFS for each Scrum team, for example. This would be the major factor in deciding if you should create a different team project or not. BTW, team project should correspond to a business project. Size should not be the determining factor for team project creation. As far as branching goes, I would try to avoid it as much as possible. Unnecessary and unplanned branching can lead to confusion and unproductivity. NuGet is a great option for handling dependencies. In fact, you can create a build definition that generate a NuGet package after each check-in.

Comment: @HosseinAarabi I'm not sure why you say on Team Project per Scrum Team, the 2012 version introduced the concept of Teams inside a Team Project that let you do Scrum of Scrum if you want. It's pretty working good.

Comment: @Nock if you have a single Team Project for all your Scrum Teams how are you handling the Board? Are all the Scrum teams using the same Board? If they are sharing the same board, it would create a lot of noise for other Scrum teams. If I am in Scrum team #1, I only want to see the sprint tasks for Team #1 on the board. Also, how is your burn down chart setup if you have all those scrum teams working in the same TP? While it is true that you can create multiple team inside a team project, it will be very hard to segregate these teams.

Comment: @Nock After doing some research and finding that it is possible to maintain multiple release cycles in a single team project, have separate Board, etc. I now agree with your answer of using a single team project.

Comment: Hello, yes with TFS 2012 the concept of Team help you do that, it's a very convenient feature, I use it all the time.

Comment: I was just looking at transitioning to a project at my company that has a messy TFS organization...7+ interdependent projects with vague acronyms like CDP, CWP, etc....and each branch under the root folder for each project contains branches of ALL THE OTHER PROJECTS they are using while working on that issue... not to mention there are many dev, integration, and stable folders with root trees for each project in it as well...I basically told them no thanks!

Comment: @HosseinAarabi: FYI I'm using multiple Teams per Team Project and it's working quite well. I use Areas to delineate things, and then I limit a given Team to a given Area.

Comment: FYI I'm using multiple Teams per Team Project and it's working quite well. I use Areas to delineate things, and then I limit a given Team to a given Area.

Answer (score 0):

As you have predicted it:-

OurCompanyLibrary would be a VS Solution.

OurCompanyLibrary.Application1 ... OurCompanyLibrary.ApplicationN would be VS Projects within that solution.

OurCompanyLibrary.ApplicationX.dlls would be references in the OurCompanyIntranet and OurCompanyInternet VS Solutions.

I'm not sure I understand your problem.

An Application VS Project in OurCompanyLibrary would be separately buildable producing its own dll that could then be referenced in the other two solutions.
If the problem is having all of the Applications under one VS Team Project (OurCompanyLibrary) then the answer would be to create a separate VS Team Project for each Application - OurCompanyLibrary1 for Application1, OurCompanyLibrary2 for Application2, etc.
The development of each Application is then totally self-contained and separate from the others.

If the problem is that you want different portions of the source in different solutions then that is achieved by adding the project to a solution.
This does mean that all of those solutions have all of the source code though.
We have something similar where I work:-
We have a solution that has 2 projects - our common business logic layer and our common data access layer.
Each of our other solutions has those projects included.
This means we can edit the source code from any solution.

I don't know if any of this will help you, but good luck with it!

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. The problem we are having is that one application (which would be it's own Team Project) spans multiple VS Solutions and those VS Solutions would have to be added to every Team Project. The OurCompanyIntranet solution has a VS project for each of the applications and one project for the views (MVC style website). The OurCompanyInternet.UI project is a website project that references every application project in the solution (OurCompanyIntranet.Appliation1 ... OurCompanyIntranet.ApplicationN). We want to structure our Solutions to match TFS.

Comment: I edited my original question to add an example of how we develop applications. I see where you are coming from with adding the projects from the other solutions to a solution for the Team Project. How do I do this in source control so we don't duplicate. Also, how would we create builds for the Application1 Team Project or would we be creating builds on the OurCompanyInternet and OurCompanyIntranet Team Projects?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an application that in running in produciton I would make minimal changes to the folder/solution structure. In TFS in your build definition you can select multiple projects or you can also put multiple solution in the build script like in the below example

[How to build 2 solutions from a single TFS team build definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431177/how-to-build-2-solutions-from-a-single-tfs-team-build-definition)

Comment: Building is not the only thing that I am concerned about. I also want to be able to only have one Team Project that spans multiple solutions so I can keep everything for that project in one place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a centralized reporting for the whole codebase, you should explore the possibility to use **one** TeamProject to host everything.
In order to then distinguish between the different components/parts you can employ separate Areas within this TeamProject.
 Check out [this](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/when-should-i-use-areas-in-tfs-instead-of-team-projects-in-team-foundation-server-2010/) very interesting article, especially the Pros/Cons section.