# Specify separate web applications within same solution - Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, visual-studio-2012, solution

I have a Visual Studio ASP.Net Web Solution.  On our live website, IIS is used to differentiate several different applications within this single solution. It works without a problem there, but when I open the entire solution up with visual studio, some parts cannot be found.

See example structure below...  If I am working on something within "Application 2", it does not recognize any code within that "App_Code" folder because it is looking at my root "App_Code" folder instead.  My question:  Is there a way to manage multiple web applications under one solution in Visual Studio?

Example structure:

```
Root - Main Application
  App_Code
  App_Data
  Folder 1
  Folder 2
  Folder 3
  web.config
  Application 2
     App_Code
     App_Data
     Folder Inside
     Another folder
     web.config
  Application 3
     App_Code
     App_Data
     Folder 1
     Folder 2
     web.config
```

Comment: do you have separated namespaces for each project?

Comment: and why application 2 and 3 inside Main application? I think they should on the same level.

Comment: It is a single project and just one namespace.  There are multiple applications within the same project.  Since these are unique applications, they have their own directories (App_Code and App_Data) and web.configs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each VS solution can have multiple projects, so... you can just add each Application as a Project in your solution.

One way to do it would be:

1. Create a new BLANK/EMPTY solution
2. Right click on the solution name and  select "Add > Existing Website" and select your ROOT folder.
3. Repeat step 2 but this time select the folder "Application 2"... do the same for all projects.

At the end you will end up with something like:

```
- SOLUTION
+- Root
+- Application 1
+- Application 2
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I currently have the solution set up with Team Foundation as a source control solution.  I wonder if I can make the current folders into separate projects without creating a new solution.

Comment: I am no expert on TFS... but I am pretty sure you can add more than 1 solution/projects to your TFS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902951/tfs-project-with-multiple-visual-studio-solutions

Comment: just add new projects in your solution and move your applications there.

Comment: If i do that and say application 2 contains an html link to some file in the Root application Ex: "/somefile.pdf" will it find it? or will the new root be the application 2 directory?  Sorry for the simple question, just trying to understand how this works.

Comment: each application has its own virtual directory?

Comment: Yes and no. In your server, "/somefile.pdf" will be found without a problem because IIS settings have not changed. In you development computer, if you are using IIS Express (with default settings), "/somefile.pdf" will not be searched in what you expect to be the ROOT folder, but the root of your application folder (In IIS Express, each application has a unique port). You could manually change IIS Express settings to allow multiple apps in the same URL. If you are using a IIS instance in your local computer, it should work depending of how you have set it up.